# The average of values when my factor is excluded

Tags: r

I wish to take average of the values when my factor is excluded. This is my data:

```
dff= data.frame(v1 =c("a,b,d","b,a,g", "f,d") , v2 = c(1,2,3) )
```

for example for `a` I wish to take average of rows that does not have `a` which is row 3 and average is 3. for `f` I wish to take average of rows without `f` which are rrow 1 and 3 and the average of V2 is (1 + 3) / 2 =1.5 My ideal output will be

```
factor   avg

  a       3
  b       3
  d       2
  f       1.5
  g       2
```

I tried two approaches: First one:

```
dff2 <- cSplit(dff, "v1",   " , ", "long")

c <- setDT(dff2)[,  .(value = (sum(dff2$v2) - sum(v2))/(nrow(dff2)-.N)) , by =  v1]
```

and the second:

```
library(tidyverse)

dff %>% separate_rows(v1,  convert = TRUE) %>%    
                     group_by(v1) %>%   
                     summarise(avg = mean(.$v2[!.$v1 %in% v1]))
```

none of them gave me the desirable outcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we can get the collection of factors using:

```
fac <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(dff$v1),split=",")))
##[1] "a" "b" "d" "g" "f"
```

then, we can compute what you want using:

```
avg <- sapply(fac, function(f) mean(ifelse(grepl(f,dff$v1), NA, dff$v2),na.rm=TRUE))
##  a   b   d   g   f 
##3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 1.5
```

Here, we use `grepl` to determine if each `fac` is found in `dff$v1`. If it is, then the `ifelse` returns `NA` for that row, and if it is not, returns the value of `dff$v2` for that row. We can then compute the `mean`, ignoring the `NA`s for those rows that `fac` is found in `dff$v1`, as you wished.

Or, if you prefer, we can put the results into a `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(factor=fac,avg=avg)
##  factor avg
##a      a 3.0
##b      b 3.0
##d      d 2.0
##g      g 2.0
##f      f 1.5
```

---

In order to have exact match using `%in%`, consider the data:

```
## Note use of stringsAsFactors=FALSE to avoid having to coerce to character
## for strsplit
dff <- data.frame(v1 =c("a,b,d","b,a,g", "a.b,f,d"), v2 = c(1,2,3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

fac <- unique(unlist(strsplit(dff$v1,split=",")))
##[1] "a"   "b"   "d"   "g"   "a.b" "f"  
avg <- sapply(fac, function(f) mean(ifelse(sapply(strsplit(dff$v1,split=","), function(d) f %in% d), NA, dff$v2),na.rm=TRUE))
##  a   b   d   g a.b   f 
##3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 1.5 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks @aichao, It works a problem that I have with grepl is I need the exact math, for instance I have both `a` and `a.b`

Comment: Try with `any(f %in% strsplit(as.character(dff$v1),split=","))` instead of `grepl(f,dff$v1)`

Comment: Sorry, I got this error Error in ifelse(grepl(f, dff$v1), NA, dff$v2, NA) : unused argument (NA)
Called from: ifelse(grepl(f, dff$v1), NA, dff$v2, NA)

Comment: Thanks aichao, even for this example , you might have a type when you pasted here

Comment: @MFR: please review now. I believe the original typo and the updated solution is now correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much. just a double check to make sure I understood the code for taking average of rows that "include" a factor should I replace it with `mean(ifelse(sapply(strsplit(dff$v1,split=","), function(d) f %in% d), dff$v2,NA )` ?

Comment: @MFR: Yes, that should work. The `ifelse` returns `dff$v2` if the condition is `TRUE` and `NA` otherwise for each row in `dff`. The condition now has **two** `sapply` loops to loop over factors **and** each row of the split `dff$v1` to generate a logical vector matching the number of rows in `dff` and this is the first argument to `ifelse`. Unfortunately, there is now two loops because I don't know how to apply `%in%` to each row of the split `dff$v1` separately in vectorized fashion.

Comment: Excuseme @aichao, I tried this in some other dataset and it doesn't work, do you have any idea why? this is one example `structure(list(sourceMedium = c("google / organic", "google / cpc, dfa / cpm, (direct) / (none), google / organic, dfa / cpc, google / cpc, google / cpc, google / cpc, google / cpc, google / organic, google / cpc, google / organic, dfa / cpc", 
"dfa / cpm", "dfa / cpm, dfa / cpm", "(direct) / (none)", "google / cpc", 
"bing / organic"), avg = c(68, 21.15384615, 0, 0, 15, 108, 37
)), .Names = c("sourceMedium", "avg"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))`

Comment: I believe the problem is that you have leading spaces so that `"google / organic"` and `" google / organic"` are different "factors". To deal with that, you can use `string::str_trim`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128411/discussion-between-mfr-and-aichao).

Comment: Good point @aichao, thank you, probably it is the reason for the problem.